# Windows Azure. Add Admin User after Sysprep

Tags: azure, admin, addition

I found out that The “Administrator” will be disabled after Sysprep.
How to add admin user after syspred?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to.

The sole purpose for running sysprep is to create IMAGE. An IMAGE saved as base VHD, which is copied each time you create a new VM out of it. And you provide the Administrator Password when you create the new VM.

Comment: I've lost some data! And need to recover! Is any way to add user to connect via RDP.